# Зачем в Python при выполнении команды print() пишется буква f?

Tags: python, python-3.x, print

Вот пример:

```
print(f'Hi, {name}')
```

Для чего эта f?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`f` - `format` только в сокращенном виде, он нужен для того чтобы можно
было что-то вставить в таких скобках `{}` попробуйте также вывести текст но без этого `f`
Пример:

```
name = "World"
print(f"Hello, {name}")
out: "Hello, World"
# Теперь без f
print("Hello, {name}")
out: Hello, {name}
# Теперь при помощи просто format
print("Hello, {}".format(name))
out: "Hello, World"
# Но можно сделать и по другому
print("Hello, %s" % name)
out: "Hello, World"
```

Подробнее [тут](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/formatirovanie-strok-metod-format.html)

Comment: А [добрые люди](https://coderoad.ru/19457227/Как-напечатать-как-printf-в-Python3#37848366) ещи и нормальный printf все же добавили

Comment: Тут сказали объяснить, зачем мне углублять человека в format если про это можно прочитать и лучше понять чем с моих слов?

Comment: Хмм, спасибо за галочку)

Answer (score 2):

Это называется F-strings(ф-строки), служит для более удобного форматирования строки, как на вывод текста, так и при вывода различных вычислений, понятно оформив их.

```
name = 'Alex'
print(f'Hello, my name is {name}') ### Hello, my name is Alex

print(f'2 x 2 = {2*2}') ### 2 x 2 = 4

whi
```

Более подробно [тут](https://python-scripts.com/f-strings)!

Answer (score -4):

Таким образом выполняется форматирование текста (или же базовое форматирование). То есть вместо:

```
print('Hi + str(name)!')
```

Мы можем написать:

```
print('Hi {name}!')
```

Обычно это используется когда приходится работать со множеством переменных при их выводе или составлении sql запроса к примеру. Также можно форматировать числа (и еще много чего дургого):

```
print("The number is:{:b}".format(123))
```

В такой записи в местах куда нужно вставить числа и/или переменнные остаются пустые {} (фигурные скобки). И уже в `.format()` в скобках записываются сами эти числа и/или переменные.

В данном примере в фигурных скобках сделана запись `{:b}` таким образом я указал что чсило `123` будет выведено в двоичном формате т.е. `110001 110010 110011`. Таких типов форматирования чисел ещё очень много.

Более подробно познакомится с форматированием Вы можете здесь:
https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/formatirovanie-strok-metod-format.html

Comment: Ставлю 100 баксов что при `print('Hi {name}!')` выведет `Hi {name}!` без подстановки `name`

Comment: Так же как и ``print('Hi + str(name)!')`` выведет именно то, что в кавычках, без всяких подстановок.

Comment: Допущено много ошибок в ответе. И новичок врядли поймёт с ваших слов